# Utility to Stamp/Watermark Unicode Text Into a PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line, unicode, utilities

I am looking for a (preferably) command line utility to stamp/watermark unicode text content into a PDF document.

I tried [PDF Stamp](http://www.verypdf.com/pdfstamp/index.htm) and a couple of others that I found over the net, but to no avail with Greek characters (e.g. ΓΔΘΛ become ÃÄÈË).

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

With sufficiently "odd" characters, you generally need to specify a font and an encoding.  I suspect that at least one of the tools you experimented with have the capability to define such things.

Reading their docs, it looks like PDFStamp will let you specify a font, but not an encoding.  That doesn't bode well.  It might always pick "Identity-H" for system fonts... worth trying.

I must admit, I'm surprised.  "Disappointed" even.  Have you contacted their email support?

Once upon a time, iText shipped with a number of command line tools that were mostly intended as examples but were none the less useful.  I suspect you could dig them out of the SVN archive on sourceforge and get them to build again, if your Java-fu is up to the task.  Just be sure to use `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` whenever you're given a choice of encodings for a font.